# Problems with callouts Mock and tests

Tags: apex, trigger, callout, mock

We have a problem in our organization and I was hoping for some advice from you on how to best tackle this.

We have a handler class that makes a callout to a Master Data Management system for account validation. That handler class is perfectly covered by it's own tests that utilize Mocking of the outbound call.

Now our business process dictates that we need to do a check every time an Account is created or updated, so we invoke that callout from an Account After trigger.

Now we run into a problem as any testmethod we have in the system that tries to construct an Account for unit testing purposes triggers the outbound callout and fails with a Fatal error: testmethods cannot invoke callouts.

Can somebody give us a hint on how to best properly deal with this?

Best regards,
Ivar

Comment: How did you implement async callout from trigger? Do you use `future` annotation, implement `Queueable` interface?

Comment: It is @future but not queueable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your trigger handler class `AccountTriggerHandler` create static field

```
@testVisible
private static Boolean skipCallout = Test.isRunningTest();
```

and then before making a callout check:

```
if(!AccountTriggerHandler.skipCallout){
    // do callout
}
```

Comment: Thanks Alexander! We were thinking along those lines. Good to get confirmation by a third party!